# How to do NOT IN query in Solr?

Tags: solr

How can I exclude a set of document IDs from Solr result set? Essentially something like

`/select?q=tag_id:367 AND NOT id:(306670,302209)`

I tried it and it does not exclude documents with those id's.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
/select?q=*:*&fq=tag_id:367 AND id:[* TO *] -id:(306670 302209)
```

That should allow you to build out add as many ids as you want without having to add `-id:302209` every time you want to eliminate an ID. The reverse is also true, you can swap the `-` with a `+` and force an array of values to be there as well.

Comment: Thx for suggesting the `q=*:*` format. The one you are suggesting still did not exclude the documents with id's 306670 and 302209. But this one does: `/select?q=*:*&fq=tag_id:367 AND -id:306670 AND -id:302209` Essentially the grouping functionality with parantheses is not working for me.

Comment: It might be because I added commas for some reason, try separating them with spaces instead. I will also update my code.

Comment: I guess the `AND id:[* TO *]` is unnecessary?

Comment: To be explicit the query is the same as `/select?q=*:*&fq=+tag_id:367 AND -id:(306670 OR 302209)`, which is the same as `/select?q=*:*&fq=+tag_id:367 AND -id:306670 AND -id:302209`

Comment: this works for my case perfectly. Another separate post suggesting to put constraint under "q" instead of "fq" doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Found one solution:

```
/select?q=tag_id:367&fq=-id:306670 AND -id:302209
```

Not sure whether this is the best way to do it though!

Comment: That's the way - you can also do id:-306670 -302209

Comment: Thx for confirming. However, the alternate syntax is throwing org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException for me.

Comment: Hmm that might be because the default search field isn't set to `id`.

Comment: Right, `id` is not the default search field.

Comment: this will work too: `/select?q=tag_id:367&fq=-id:(306670 OR 302209)`