# NOT condition usage in solr query

Tags: javascript, php, apache, cakephp, solr

In my project i am using solr api for searching the documents with the given words. I am getting the result with the 'AND' and 'OR' conditions but i want to use the 'NOT' condition also. But i have tried and i am not getting the exact result.

I want to get the results for

```
(((Php AND mysql) OR (ROR OR .Net)) NOT (Java))
(((Php AND mysql) OR (ROR OR .Net)) NOT (Java AND Cake))
```

if i will write like this

```
(*:* NOT Java)
```

then i am getting the results withut java. So Please guide me how to use 'NOT' condition for solr query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do NOT IN query in Solr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855830/how-to-do-not-in-query-in-solr)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying it on same field
you can try to build the query like this 
replace the 'reference' with your field name

reference:TSP AND reference:LAE AND NOT reference:N133

and for different fields with other combinations

1. reference:TSP AND name:Test AND NOT metadata:Superseded
2. reference:(TSP AND LAE) AND name:Test AND NOT metadata:Superseded
3. reference:(TSP AND LAE) AND name:(Test OR Wheel) AND NOT metadata:Superseded
4. reference:(TSP AND LAE) OR name:(Test OR Wheel) AND NOT metadata:Superseded
5. reference:(TSP AND LAE) OR name:(Test AND Wheel) AND NOT metadata:Superseded

Comment: Thanks @Abhijit, I am trying to get the result from same field. And i have one doubt, if i will write NOT java then will it exclude also 'Javascript'?

Comment: It all depends on how you have indexed it...mean what is the field type...how your field type is build of ...means whats the analyser, tokeniser been used for indexing and querying...The best way to try all this is use the Solr admin tool...it helps you a lot in analysing it ...