# How to remove/exclude a doc based on unqiue id from the solr result

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using solr4.10 , i have few document ids that must not be displayed from any search query.Could some provide inputs as how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/select?q=*:*&fq=tag_id:367 AND id:[* TO *] -id:(306670 302209)
```

Add you document ids inside **-id:(X, Y, Z)** to exclude them.

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855830/how-to-do-not-in-query-in-solr).

Comment: Thanks, But i would want to do it not on query but say something like elevation.xml .Here anything i can do in general not specific to a search word. So before hand i can ignore the ids which are  not required

Answer (score 0):

if you know the ids you can add them in the filter query.

`fq` : This parameter can be used to specify a query that can be used to restrict the super set of documents that can be returned