# Usage of UNION and MINUS in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene

I am working in solr where i want to use the combinations of UNION and MINUS in SOLR. I have formulated oracle query.

```
select * from TESTTABLE where (FT = 'PE' and emis between 10 and 20) or (FT = 'DI' and emis between 10 and 15) 
union (
select * from TESTTABLE where (FT <> 'PE' or emis not between 10 and 20) and (FT <> 'DI' or emis not between 10 and 15) 
minus
select * from TESTTABLE where (FT = 'PE' and emis not between 10 and 20) or (FT = 'DI' and emis not between 10 and 15) 
);
```

I want to formulate an equivalent SOLR. Please assis me on to convert the oracle query to SOLR.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to build that in Solr, just take into account:

1. you can use parens like in sql
2. UNION: just OR two conditions x OR y
3. MINUS: just join both conditions with AND NOT: x AND NOT y
4. remember to put all those inside a fq, use `*:*` for q
5. watch out with the 'NOT x', in solr sometimes you a little hack to make it work correctly, see [here for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855830/how-to-do-not-in-query-in-solr). Might depend on the solr version

Answer (score 0):

So for your example : Fetch books in Comics and Filmography with age range of 10 and 25 and assuming three fields bookName, bookType and age i will do the following :-

q=bookType:Comics bookType:Filmography&fq=age:[10 TO 25]

No gap between the 2 bookType clauses in main query implies an OR. i.e. bring a Comic or a Filmography. and the age range in the filter query i.e. fq filters out results which are not having age between 10 and 25.